# How can I speed up a slow iMac from 2017?

Tags: imac, hdd

My iMac is running very slow and I want to know the solution for it. Should I change the HDD or use external SSD. If I use external SSD will Graphic Cards work fine or will give problems. Here is the Etrecheck report of the issue:

```
EtreCheck version: 5.7.2 (5247)
Report generated: 2023-07-27 22:43:40
Download EtreCheck from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 8:07
Performance: Below Average
Sandbox: Enabled
Full drive access: Disabled

Problem: Computer is too slow
Description: 
When I open Safari then every open window sticks and interrupts. Compu
ter is too slow. I am looking for a solution which can fix this proble
m permanently. I am unable to apple iOS or android emulator or can’t e
ven do game development in unity

Major Issues:
  Anything that appears on this list needs immediate attention. 
  Hard drive too slow - The hard drive in this computer is too slow.
  Runaway process - A process is using a large percentage of your CPU.
  Unsigned files - There are unsigned software files installed that could be adware and should be reviewed.

Minor Issues:
  These issues do not need immediate attention but they may indicate future problems or opportunities for improvement. 
  No Time Machine backup - Time Machine backup not found.
  Heavy network usage - This computer has recently restarted and has high network usage.
  Unsigned files - There are unsigned software files installed. Apple has said that unsigned software will not run by default in a future version of the operating system.
  Limited drive access - More information may be available with Full Drive Access.
  Kernel extensions present - This computer has kernel extensions that may not work in the future.

Hardware Information:
  iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5-inch, 2017)
  iMac Model: iMac18,2
  3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5 (i5-7400) CPU: 4-core
  8 GB RAM - Upgradeable by an Apple Authorized Service Provider
    BANK 0/DIMM0 - 4 GB DDR4 SO-DIMM 2400  
    BANK 1/DIMM0 - 4 GB DDR4 SO-DIMM 2400  

Video Information:
  Radeon Pro 555 - VRAM: 2 GB
    iMac (built-in) 4096 x 2304

Drives:
  disk0 - APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E632 1.00 TB (Mechanical - 5400 RPM) 
  Internal SATA 3 Gigabit Serial ATA
    disk0s1 - EFI (MS-DOS FAT32) [EFI] 210 MB
    disk0s2 [APFS Container] 499.86 GB
      disk2 [APFS Virtual drive] 499.86 GB (Shared by 6 volumes)
        disk2s1 (APFS) [APFS Container] (Shared)
          disk2s1s1 - M**********I (APFS) [APFS Snapshot] (Shared - 9.58 GB used)
        disk2s2 - Preboot (APFS) [APFS Preboot] (Shared - 1.90 GB used)
        disk2s3 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (Shared)
        disk2s4 - VM (APFS) [APFS VM] (Shared - 5.37 GB used)
        disk2s6 - M************  - Data (APFS) [APFS Virtual drive] (Shared - 347.31 GB used)
        disk2s7 - Update (APFS) (Shared - 18 MB used)
    disk0s3 [APFS Container] 500.13 GB
      disk1 [APFS Virtual drive] 500.13 GB (Shared by 2 volumes)
        disk1s1 - M***********I (APFS) (Shared - 293.89 GB used)
        disk1s2 - Update (APFS) (Shared)

Mounted Volumes:
  disk1s1 - M***********I
    500.13 GB (Shared - 293.89 GB used, 206.13 GB available, 206.08 GB free)
    APFS
    Mount point: /Volumes/M***********I

  disk2s1s1 - M**********I [APFS Snapshot]
    499.86 GB (Shared - 9.58 GB used, 138.73 GB available, 134.37 GB free)
    APFS
    Mount point: /
    Read-only: Yes

  disk2s2 - Preboot [APFS Preboot]
    499.86 GB (Shared - 1.90 GB used, 134.37 GB free)
    APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/Preboot

  disk2s4 - VM [APFS VM]
    499.86 GB (Shared - 5.37 GB used, 134.37 GB free)
    APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/VM

  disk2s6 - M************  - Data [APFS Virtual drive]
    499.86 GB (Shared - 347.31 GB used, 138.73 GB available, 134.37 GB free)
    APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/Data
    Encrypted

  disk2s7 - Update
    499.86 GB (Shared - 18 MB used, 134.37 GB free)
    APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/Update

Network:
  Interface en0: Ethernet
  Interface en1: Wi-Fi
    802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
  Interface bridge0: Thunderbolt Bridge
  Interface en4: iPhone
  Interface en6: iPhone 2

System Software:
  13.4.1 13.4.1 (22F770820d) 
  Time since boot: Less than an hour

Notifications:
  Notifications not available without Full Drive Access.

Security:
  Gatekeeper: Enabled
  System Integrity Protection: Enabled

  Antivirus software: Apple

Unsigned Files:
  Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist
    Executable: /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart
    Details: Exact match found in the legitimate list - probably OK

  Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdaterDaemon.plist
    Executable: /Applications/OneDrive.app/Contents/StandaloneUpdaterDaemon.xpc/Contents/MacOS/StandaloneUpdaterDaemon
    Details: Exact match found in the legitimate list - probably OK

  Launchd: /Library/Apple/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dt.RemotePairingDataVaultHelper.plist
    Executable: /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RemotePairing.framework/Versions/A/Resources/bin/RemotePairingDataVaultHelper

  Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.OneDriveUpdaterDaemon.plist
    Executable: /Applications/OneDrive.app/Contents/OneDriveUpdaterDaemon.xpc/Contents/MacOS/OneDriveUpdaterDaemon
    Details: Exact match found in the legitimate list - probably OK

  Apps: 24

System Extensions:
  [Running] ProtonVPN OpenVPN - version 3.1.4 (ProtonVPN AG - 2023-05-15)
    Application: /Applications/ProtonVPN.app - version 3.1.4 (ProtonVPN AG - 2023-07-11)

  [Running] ProtonVPN WireGuard - version 3.1.4 (ProtonVPN AG - 2023-05-15)
    Application: /Applications/ProtonVPN.app - version 3.1.4 (ProtonVPN AG - 2023-07-11)

Kernel Extensions:
  /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox
    VBoxDrv.kext - org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (6.1.40)
    VBoxNetAdp.kext - org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp (6.1.40)
    VBoxNetFlt.kext - org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt (6.1.40)
    VBoxUSB.kext - org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (6.1.40)

System Launch Agents:
  [Not Loaded]  19 Apple tasks
  [Loaded]  195 Apple tasks
  [Running]  169 Apple tasks
  [Other]  2 Apple tasks

System Launch Daemons:
  [Not Loaded]  37 Apple tasks
  [Loaded]  190 Apple tasks
  [Running]  158 Apple tasks
  [Other]  2 Apple tasks

Launch Agents:
  [Not Loaded] com.microsoft.update.agent.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2023-01-12)

Launch Daemons:
  [Running] com.cloudflare.1dot1dot1dot1.macos.warp.daemon.plist (Cloudflare Inc. - installed 2023-07-26)
  [Loaded] com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdaterDaemon.plist (? f39826f0  - installed 2020-12-29)
  [Loaded] com.microsoft.OneDriveUpdaterDaemon.plist (? a510a00  - installed 2020-12-29)
  [Not Loaded] com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2023-01-12)
  [Not Loaded] com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2022-05-26)
  [Not Loaded] org.virtualbox.startup.plist (? 700b9385  - installed 2022-11-18)
  [Loaded] us.zoom.ZoomDaemon.plist (Zoom Video Communications, Inc. - installed 2023-07-08)

User Launch Agents:
  [Running] com.imobie.AnyTransToolHelpers.plist (2QJGLWL8Y6 - installed 2022-06-24)

User Login Items:
  [Loaded] LoginLauncherApp (Cloudflare Inc. - installed 2023-07-26)
    Modern Login Item
    /Applications/Cloudflare WARP.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/LoginLauncherApp.app

  [Not Loaded] Pomy Login Helper (App Store - installed 2023-01-28)
    Modern Login Item
    /Applications/Pomy.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/Pomy Login Helper.app

  [Loaded] ProtonVPNStarter (ProtonVPN AG - installed 2023-07-11)
    Modern Login Item
    /Applications/ProtonVPN.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/ProtonVPNStarter.app

  [Loaded] ScreenColorFilterHelper (App Store - installed 2023-01-28)
    Modern Login Item
    /Applications/Screen Colors Filter — Color Tint & Dim HEV Block.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/ScreenColorFilterHelper.app

  [Not Loaded] WhatsApp Login Helper (App Store - installed 2023-07-25)
    Modern Login Item
    /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/WhatsApp Login Helper.app

User Internet Plug-ins:
  User Internet Plug-ins need Full Drive Access

User Audio Plug-ins:
  User Audio Plug-ins need Full Drive Access

User iTunes Plug-ins:
  User iTunes Plug-ins need Full Drive Access

Backup:
  Time Machine Not Configured!

Performance:
  System Load: 1.96 (1 min ago) 2.71 (5 min ago) 2.49 (15 min ago)
  Nominal I/O speed: 7.80 MB/s
  File system: 69.12 seconds
  Write speed: 30 MB/s
  Read speed: 35 MB/s

CPU Usage Snapshot:
  Type Overall
  System: 9 %
  User: 20 %
  Idle: 71 %

Top Processes Snapshot by CPU:
  Process (count) CPU (Source - Location)
  Other processes 96.15 % (?)
  EtreCheck 15.89 % (App Store)
  Brave Browser 1.12 % (Brave Software, Inc.)
  exchangesyncd 0.87 % (Apple)
  AMPDevicesAgent 0.37 % (Apple)

Top Processes Snapshot by Memory:
  Process (count) RAM usage (Source - Location)
  EtreCheck 711 MB (App Store)
  AppleSpell 148 MB (Apple)
  Brave Browser 147 MB (Brave Software, Inc.)
  Safari 100 MB (Apple)
  accountsd 42 MB (Apple)

Top Processes Snapshot by Network Use:
  Process (count) Input / Output (Source - Location)
  Other processes 1.30 GB / 60 MB (?)
  rapportd 3 KB / 4 KB (Apple)
  routined 0 B / 0 B (Apple)
  homed 0 B / 0 B (Apple)
  NotificationCenter 0 B / 0 B (Apple)

Virtual Memory Information:
  Physical RAM: 8 GB

  Free RAM: 1.43 GB
  Used RAM: 4.23 GB
  Cached files: 2.34 GB

  Available RAM: 3.77 GB
  Swap Used: 122 MB

Software Installs (past 30 days):
  Install Date Name (Version)
  2023-07-02 macOS 13.4.1 (13.4.1)
  2023-07-07 XProtectPlistConfigData (2169)
  2023-07-08 Zoom (5.15.2.19786)
  2023-07-14 macOS Rapid Security Response 13.4.1 (c) (13.4.1 (c))
  2023-07-21 XProtectPayloads (105)
  2023-07-24 Dashlane (6.2328.0)
  2023-07-25 WhatsApp (2.2330.11)
  2023-07-26 Cloudflare WARP

Diagnostics Information (past 7-30 days):
  Directory /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports is not accessible.
  Enable Full Drive Access to see more information.

End of report
```

Comment: The HDD in probably failing.  I’d open up the iMac and install an SSD then do a nice clean install of macOS.  Depending on your memory usage, I’d upgrade the RAM since it will be open at that time.

Comment: An External SSD will also work well, if you don't want to open the case. It has no effect on the graphics card. But if you (or someone else) is going to open it up, you might want to add more RAM at the same time.

Comment: Did you run Activity Monitor or `top` to identify "Runaway process - A process is using a large percentage of your CPU"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I assume your iMac (21.5 inch, Mid 2017) was original equipped with only a HDD and no SSD. In other words, there was no prior Fusion drive arrangement. In this case, you can [only internally install legacy SATA 3.0 type drives](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/imac-aluminum-tapered-edge-faq/how-to-upgrade-imac-hard-drive-aluminum-2012-2013.html), which limits drive transfers to maximum of 6 Gb/s. So even if you replace the internal HDD with a SSD, the limit is still 6 Gb/s. The Thunderbolt 3 ports on your Mac have a maximum transfer rate of 40 Gb/s.

**You will not be able to achieve the performance of any 2017 iMac which was shipped from Apple with a internal SSD by replacing your internal HDD with an internal SSD. This is because Apple installed PCIe internal SSDs and you can only replace your HDD with SATA SSD. PCIe SDDs are far faster that SATA SSDs.**

Your Mac configured with a single SATA HDD should preform well enough to be usable under macOS, provided macOS is installed on a volume that is JHFS+ (Mac OS Extended Journaled) formatted. For your Mac, this would limit the macOS versions to Sierra and High Sierra. Mojave through Ventura requires APFS. My experience with my 2013 iMac has been macOS performs poorly when installed on a single SATA HDD where APFS is used. The cheapest solution would be to install High Sierra on a JHFS+ formatted internal volume. If you do so, you most likely will find Safari is not be compatible with many websites. You can try using other browsers that are up to date such as Edge, Firefox, Chrome and Brave.

If you choose to use a different drive, here are some sample numbers.

[OWC offers two different 1 TB SATA SSDs](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/imac-21.5-inch/2013-2019). The specs are given below.

|  | Mercury Electra 6G | Mercury Extreme Pro 6G |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Price | 64.99 USD | 94.99 USD |
| Price with Upgrade Kit | 84.99 USD | 113.99 USD |
| Limited Warranty | 3 Year | 5 Year |
| Sequential Read (Max) | 540 MB/s | 550 MB/s |
| Sequential Write (Max) | 500 MB/s | 530 MB/s |

[Crucial offers two different 1 TB SATA SSDs](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/apple/imac-(retina-4k--21*5-inch--2017)-imac18-2#). The specs are given below.

|  | BX500 | MX500 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Price | 47.99 USD | 47.99 USD |
| Limited Warranty | 3 Year | 5 Year |
| Sequential Read (Max) | 540 MB/s | 560 MB/s |
| Sequential Write (Max) | 500 MB/s | 510 MB/s |

Below are some sample external 1 TB USB Type C (USB 3.2 Gen2) SSDs.

|  | [Samsung Portable T7](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/portable-solid-state-drives/portable-ssd-t7-usb-3-2-1tb--blue--mu-pc1t0h-am/) | [SanDisk Extreme Portable V2](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/portable-drives/sandisk-extreme-usb-3-2-ssd#SDSSDE61-1T00-G25) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Price | 89.99 USD | 79.99 USD |
| Limited Warranty | 3 Year | 5 Year |
| Sequential Read (Max) | 1050 MB/s | 1050 MB/s |
| Sequential Write (Max) | 1000 MB/s | 1000 MB/s |

Below are some sample external 1 TB Thunderbolt 3 SSDs.

|  | [OWC Envoy Pro FX](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/owc-envoy-pro-fx?utm_term=portable%20ssd&utm_campaign=&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&hsa_acc=9360794409&hsa_cam=20395092237&hsa_grp=153130865953&hsa_ad=667033213856&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=kwd-4828352042&hsa_kw=portable%20ssd&hsa_mt=b&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3MSMtf6wgAMVZfTjBx3TuAS5EAAYASAAEgLSHfD_BwE) | [SanDisk PRO-G40](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/portable-drives/sandisk-professional-pro-g40-ssd?ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIgb7h8fuwgAMVOfPjBx3VfQmhEAQYAyABEgK3IvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!15012!3!!!!x!!!18290413092!&utm_medium=pdsh2&utm_source=gads&utm_campaign=SanDiskProfessional-NA-US-PLA&utm_content=&utm_term=SDPS31H-001T-GBCND#SDPS31H-001T-GBCND) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Price | 219.99 USD | 159.99 USD |
| Limited Warranty | 3 Year | 5 Year |
| Sequential Read (Max) | 2800 MB/s | 3000 MB/s |
| Sequential Write (Max) | 2800 MB/s† | 2500 MB/s |

<sup>†Since OWC did distinguish between read and write, this value will probably be sightly lower than 2800.</sup>

The external drives are much faster, but more expensive. There is also the possibility of building you own external drive by putting an internal SSD in a Thunderbolt 3 enclosure.

Comment: Many thanks for this detail answer. In India OWC is not available so can you help with Western Digitial or Crucial brand please.

Comment: Are you considering an internal or external drive? I think SanDisk is a Western Digital brand.

Comment: I am considering an internal one as my child might start playing with external SSD

Comment: Thanks David. Please help me with two more questions: 1. Can I be able to used inbuilt graphic card when I install external SSD as good as internal SSD? 2. Can I used SSD of USB 3.2 in my iMac whose USB if of type C and of USB 3.1?

Comment: The only effect an external SSD would have on the builtin graphics would be with respect to connecting external displays. If you need to share a USB-C port with both a SSD and a Display, then there would be limitation of 4k@60Hz with DP 1.4 support.

Comment: Generally speaking, USB 3.2 devices are backward compatible with USB 3.1 ports. For example, you should be able to plug a USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 SSD into an USB-C port on your Mac, but the transfer speed would be 10 Gb/s instead of 20 Gb/s.

Comment: I don’t need to connect external display. So in conclusion you meant that an external 3.2 sata SSD will work better than an internal SSD. Graphic card performance will be same like internal SSD unless I want to use external display.

Comment: When plugged into your Mac, an USB drive will operate at either 480 Mb/s, 5 Gb/s or 10 Gb/s. If you are going to use a external USB SSD, then make sure the drive has a maximum transfer rate of at least 10 Gb/s. For example, USB 3.1 Gen 2, USB 3.2 Gen 2 or USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 all mean the same thing and operate at a maximum of 10 Gb/s. An USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 SSD has a maximum of 20 Gb/s, but will operate a 10 Gb/s when plugged into your Mac.

Comment: I just wanted to ask one more question. You suggested me to install High Sierra in Mac as a cheapest solution. I want to know that could I install latest macOS in external SSD or there also I need to install High Sierra. Am asking because I will also install development framework like unity and android studio.

Comment: I responded to your question by posting [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464926/should-i-install-high-sierra-in-external-ssd-in-imac-2017-model-for-good-perform/464930#464930).

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely update the HDD to an SSD internally if you can.

- Using an external SSD is fine, but internal is usually the best option.

Additionally, if the RAM is not soldered (which it doesn't look like it is), I'd update that as well to 16GB.

Fresh install of macOS could potentially help if you are facing other issues (kernel crashes/system crashes etc)