# Should I install High Sierra in external SSD in iMac 2017 model for good performance or I can install latest version as well?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, ssd, performance, external-disk

I have an iMac 2017 version with HDD and no fusion drive. HDD has slowed down so I am planning to use an external SSD. In my earlier question a generous user told me that in my model of iMac High Sierra will work better as APFS don’t work well. I just want to know that if I use an external SSD to install MacOS then can I install latest version or use only High Sierra.

Comment: I would worry about malware at least as much as about performance; if your host gets infected by a cryptocurrency miner (for example), that would hurt performance at least as much as running more aggressive search indexing &c; and the newer OS features can mostly be turned off. (Moreover, you don't need to worry about newer OS features encrypting your data for ransom).

Answer (score 2):

You can install Ventura (macOS 13), which is [compatible](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213264) with your Mac. The latest is Sonoma (macOS 14), which Apple has stated is [not compatible](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213772) with your Mac. If your internal drive is running High Sierra or newer, then you should be able to download the Ventura installer application from the Apple App Store. A link to Ventura in the Apple App Store can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683#appstore). You can use this application to install Ventura on an external APFS formatted SSD.

You can install Ventura to an external SSD without also having High Sierra installed on this SSD.

Comment: I am using Ventura in in internal HDD however you suggested me to start using High Sierra. If I install Ventura in my new external SSD will there be performance issue again or should I stick with High Sierra in External SSD as well.

Comment: Install Ventura in the external SSD. The performance issue has to do with HDDs. Your external drive is a SSD.